# How to add a div above another element (video) to perfectly cover it?

Tags: html, css

I have a video element

```
<video id="interviewRecorder" width="100%"></video>
```

I want to add a div just at adjacent DOM like:

```
<video id="interviewRecorder" width="100%"></video>
<div id="coverIt"></div>
```

So it perfectly covers the video.
Notice that  may be included into complex DOM.

I tried with absolute positioning, but could not make it work

```
let rect = interviewRecorder.getBoundingClientRect();
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'coverIt',
    css: {
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": rect.top,
        "left": rect.left,
        "width": rect.width,
        "height": rect.height,
        "background": "grey",
    }
}).insertAfter(interviewRecorder);
```

Looks like absolute is absolute to relative positioning. I have no idea on how to position it absolute / screen coordinates.

Comment: And isn't it better to insert video in div and set relative and then id "coverIt" as absolute?

Comment: You need to wrap both in a container, and then position the "coverIt" div over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote above, it is better to do it via html and css without jquery or pure js. Below is an example of how this can be done with jquery.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.item').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.layer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

video {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="movie item" src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mov-file.mov"></video>
<div class="layer item">TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `position:relative;` to body and then apply `position:absolute` to your div and your video element and then add `z-index:10;` to div and `z-index:5` to video element. so that
the div is stacked above the video element.

Note: I kept z-index values randomly you just have to make sure that the z-index of div is greater than the z-index of the video element.